# the meaning of "His hands wash together"

Tags: sentence-meaning

> He looks up. Like an after-image, the form of the tears swims in his
>   eyes; the picture blurs. He blinks. Someone is walking towards him. It
>   is George Cavendish. **His hands wash together**, his face is a mask of
>   concern.
>
> — Wolf Hall by Hilary Mantel

Does the bold sentence mean that he rubs and wrings his hands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it seems that way.  His hands would be making a gesture like washing.  This is consistent with a look of "concern" on his face.

On the other hand (pun not intended!), the observer has blurred vision, so he could be seeing the hands as in a blurred painting, "washed" together as if painted in a blurred, indistinct manner.

But the  "mask of concern" belies this interpretation, as he had to *see clearly* to even tell that it was George Cavendish, let alone to notice the "mask of concern" on his face.